# Is there a way to create on boarding screen similar to telegram in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, telegram

I'm a flutter newbie and I love both the telegram apps (Telegram and Telegram X), the on boarding screen of these apps are awesome. I want to create on boarding screen similar to that in flutter with the same animation, is there a way I can do that?

Comment: Please provide screenshots and relevant information. And try to be specific.

Comment: sure you can do that.check how to build intro screens and desired animations and youre good to go